# Benchmarking fetching data from internet

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am working with a lot of APIs and doing some experiments, and I want to know what's the best way to know how much time it takes to execute a particular request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Instruments.  Always.  Forever.

It is an extremely useful tool, and has lots of built-in performance measurements.  In addition, you can save the results for later comparison.

Comment: What exactly in Instruments can measure this kind of stuff?

Comment: Umm, you must not have tried it yet.  A better question would be what tool in instruments will NOT help you measure this kind of stuff.  Personally, I turn a bunch on to get an overall feel for what's happening, then measure specifics.  However, if you want to start somewhere specific, the one called "Time Profiler" seems to be a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

It compares different fetch methods including : NSXMLParser , libxml2, TBXML, TouchXML, KissXML , TinyXML and GDataXML.

You can download the app and see the mean download time for each method.